# Transforming map with "custom" CRS to WGS84?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

My map opens with QGIS saying "This layer seems to have no projection specification" and generates the following CRS:
+proj=aea +lat_1=31.5 +lat_2=24 +lat_0=24 +lon_0=-84 +x_0=400000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

Looks like some form of Lat/Lon coordinates.  How can I transform to WGS?

Comment: What do you mean by map. Do you mean a Raster file or a shapefile. If you want to change the projection of your files, you can simply right click on your file and export it into a different CRS (4326). If you want to change the projection of your project, look at the bottom right of your page where it says EPSG:xxxx. click on that and change it to the projection you would like to visualize your project.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! What are the extents of the layer? Where did the data come from? Ask them/check the website to see if there's any information.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS try to read the CRS from the *.qpj* file, if exists. In your case, it doesn't.

When not finding a *.qpj* file, try to read the projection parameters from a *.prj* file. And write a custom CRS with that parameters.

In your case, seems to me that you file has the [EPSG:3086](https://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3086&reportDetail=long&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=&r=81) CRS, but was saved by another software (because a *.qpj* file was not written).

You can export the layer to reproject it to WGS84.